# How to print a column using awk command line and add header

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a problem and would appreciate any assistance. I have test1.txt file with the following columns:

```
column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|column6|column7|column8|
```

I then run the following to target specific columns.

```
cat test1.txt | awk -F "|" '{ print $2, $3, $4, $6, $7}' > teste.csv
```

The CSV file outputs the result in 1 line like so:

```
column2 column3 column4 column6 column7
```

but what i want is something like

```
header2|header3|header4|header6|header7
column2|column3|column4|column6|column7
```

Would you be able to help me fix the above and  - also how can i then add headers after getting the correct result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Bodo I have amended - sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @Maskiin Thank you. No problem. As you are new here, it's normal that you don't know all the "rules" of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that the columns should be separated with `|` instead of space, you have to set the output field separator `OFS` to the same value as the input field separator `FS`.

```
awk -F "|" -v 'OFS=|' '{ print $2, $3, $4, $6, $7}' test1.txt > teste.csv
```

You can use the `BEGIN` condition to add commands for printing a header. In this case you also can put the assignement to OFS there.

```
awk -F "|" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS; print "header2|header3|header4|header6|header7" } { print $2, $3, $4, $6, $7}' test1.txt > teste.csv
```

With the input shown in the question this prints

```
header2|header3|header4|header6|header7
column2|column3|column4|column6|column7
```

Comment: Thanks.I have tried but still it shows like below ``` header2|header3|header4|header6|header7
column2FScolumn3FScolumn4FScolumn6FScolumn7 ```

Comment: @Maskiin Please also edit your question as suggested in the comments below your question. This site is not only to answer the question for you personally, but also serves as a reference for others that may have a similar question. That's why your question should be clear and easy to understand. Currently the answers are partially based on guessing about your requirements.

Comment: happy to edit my question - it doesn't let me. I am new to the site apologies in advance for my ignorance

Comment: @Maskiin Below your question there should be written in gray something like "share edit delete flag". Click on "edit" to edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have referenced a csv (comma separated value output in your question), wit th sample data in the file columns, you can run:

```
awk -F\| 'BEGIN { OFS=",";print "COLUMN1"OFS"COLUMN2"OFS"COLUMN3"OFS"COLUMN4"OFS"COLUMN5"OFS"COLUMN6"OFS"COLUMN7"OFS"COLUMN8"OFS } { $1=$1 }1' columns
```

Set the output to , in the BEGIN section and print the headers required (in the example COLUMN1,COLUMN2 etc) with the new OFS. Then take each line, set $1 to $1 to action a change on $0, taking account of the new OFS. Use 1 to print the new line.

Output:

```
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5,COLUMN6,COLUMN7,COLUMN8,
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating more - perhaps using my example? Thanks

Comment: I have used your example? I have also assumed the output you need

Answer (score 0):

To add the headers

`awk 'BEGIN {print "Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6|Column7|Column8"} {print}' table > test1.txt`

To add the columns you would like, into the teste.csv

`cat test1.txt| awk -F '|' '{print $2, $3, $4, $6, $7}' > teste.csv`